# Implement mdbootstrap with laravel project to make it work in IE11

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, internet-explorer-11, mdbootstrap

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and recently started to use mdbootstrap (pro). 
While everything works in Chrome or Firefox, Internet Explorer 11 makes problems. 
I can't get the JavaScript part working. Here is how I implemented it (jquery is imported by bootstrap.js):

**master.blade.php (bottom)**

```
<script src="{{ URL::asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/mdbootstrap/mdb.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/mdbootstrap/addons-pro/stepper.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/mdbootstrap/addons/datatables.min.js') }}"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.stepper').mdbStepper();
        $('.mdb-select').materialSelect();
    });
</script>
```

Here are some examples for errors that are thrown:
**On every page:**

```
SCRIPT438: The object doesn't support the property or method "materialSelect".  
SCRIPT1014: invalid character
```

**On a page that uses the stepper:**

```
The Object doesn't support the property or method "easeOutQuad".
```

Well you get the point. It seems that IE doesn't recognize the imported functions.

**On the landing page:**

```
"WOW" is undefined.
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it by transpiling it with babel on my own.
This is followed by two other errors but for those I will create a new question.